# Core Web App Broken Out of the Box

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.1

I just installed VS 2017 and installed all of the ASP.NET options.  I created a new ASP.NET Core 1.1 web site and just tried to build it (I haven't done anything to the project) but the core references are all broken, and all of the namespaces are broken.....

[image: Broken Nuget References]

Nuget packet manager shows the Core library up-to-date:

[image: Nuget References Installed]

Right clicking the solution and say Restore Nuget Packages:

> All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
>
> Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.0018163
>
> ========== Finished ==========

Why are these references not working?  Project configuration shows target is ".NETCoreApp 1.1".

Comment: What happened after you did a Restore the NuGet Packages?

Comment: i had the same problem, but it works after i restore the NuGet Packages, if you check your VS option/settings, there is a offline SDKs folder (in my program files sub folder)

Comment: If have the offline SDK folder setup, and Nuget says no packages to update, from the GUI manage screen or the command line......

Comment: If you right-click on the solution node in the Solution Explorer, and choose Restore NuGet Packages, does that fix the problem?

Comment: From the output: 
All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.0018163